# Delete array object in java script

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of object and it looks like this, I want to remove attributeType object and get a new one.
How can I delete object in array?

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "version": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "attributeInputs": {
        "0": {
            "id": 4,
            "position": 0,
            "label": "display",
            "attributeType": {
                "id": 3,
                "label": "Input",
                "fieldType": "TEXT"
            },
        },
        "1": {
            "id": 5,
            "position": 3,
            "label": "price",
            "attributeType": {
                "id": 5,
                "label": "Price",
                "fieldType": "PRICE"
            },
        }
    }
}
```

I would like delete AttributeType and it should look like this:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "version": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "attributeInputs": {
        "0": {
            "id": 4,
            "position": 0,
            "label": "display",
        },
        "1": {
            "id": 5,
            "position": 3,
            "label": "price",
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no array in your question.

Comment: [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` on the `attributeInputs` field and delete the key `attributeType`:

```js
const obj = {
    "id": 2,
    "version": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "attributeInputs": {
        "0": {
            "id": 4,
            "position": 0,
            "label": "display",
            "attributeType": {
                "id": 3,
                "label": "Input",
                "fieldType": "TEXT"
            },
        },
        "1": {
            "id": 5,
            "position": 3,
            "label": "price",
            "attributeType": {
                "id": 5,
                "label": "Price",
                "fieldType": "PRICE"
            },
        }
    }
}

Object.keys(obj.attributeInputs).forEach(o => delete obj.attributeInputs[o].attributeType )

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: You haven't found a similar _"how to delete a property of an object"_ question here on SO? A mystery...

Answer (score 0):

first, let's store the object in a variable called myObject.
now let's work on the variable myObject.

```
myObject.attributeInputs = Object.keys(myObject.attributeInputs).map(key=>{
    const {attributeType,...newObj}=myObject.attributeInputs[key];
    return newObj;
});
```

it's not clean code, but it works.